# Allocation of more than 2gb fails on 64 bit binary

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, malloc

On a 64 bit linux machine I wrote the following small C program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    #define BLOCK_SIZE (1024*1024)
    int i;

    for (i = 1; ; i++)
    {
        char *p = (char *)malloc(i * BLOCK_SIZE);
        if (p == 0)
            break;
        *p = 13;
        free(p);
    }

    printf ("Allocated max %d MB\n", (i - 1));

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile this with `-O0 -m64`, I can allocate 2047 MB on my desktop system. If I compile the same program with `-O0 -m32` 3829 MB.

Why is the maximal malloc size for a 32 bit binary larger than for a 64 bit binary on the same machine?

Edit: If I activate the optimizer with `-O3`, the maximal amount of memory is 20588 on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Have you tried this only a couple of times, or is the result consistent for multiple (like tens or even hundreds) runs of your program? Also, are the result similar when you run your program straight after boot compared to after you have your computer running a couple of hours or even days?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to store a number greater than 2^31 in a signed 32 bit `int`. It does not fit. Use `size_t` instead for the size that you pass to `malloc`. Change the type of `i` to `size_t`.

Comment: With that correction, I was able to allocate 32274 megabytes (Debian/Sid/x86-64, 16GB RAM, 16GB swap)